# How do I get all process HANDLES or PIDs with the same name in cpp?

Tags: c++, windows

I have more than 1 process with the same name and I need to kill all but one, for that I belive I would need the PIDs or the process handles.
Is there a way to get either of them by the executable name?

Comment: Are you using PowerShell (which would be `Get-Process`) or CMD (which would be `tasklist`)?

Comment: I am using a c++ program with windows libraries